# CSS: How to make a textbox value background color?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the textbox text/value to have a background color just like when it is selected/highlighted but without selecting it. Just like using the `<mark></mark>` tag but this time, it is inside the textbox. Is there a way to do that? I'm ok if you use javascript.

Comment: _I'm ok if you use javascript._ And we were ok if you had tried something and would show your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type = "text" class ="textbackcolor">
```

CSS

```
/* Background Color */
.textbackcolor {
background-color : #99FFCC;
border: 1px solid #008000;
width: 230px;
}
```

Refer http://www.cssportal.com/form-elements/text-box.php for more styles

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS for styling.  You can do:

```
input {
    background: #f00;
}
```

to make the background red, for example.  You can also use a specific class for your textbox and use the above rule on that class, instead of all inputs, like i have done.